# how to implement a previous button on form using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

how to implement a previous button on form, when users click on it , they can back to previous page?

thanks

Comment: Previous button means: 'the button before current button'. Did you mean button to previous form? Or button to previous page?

Comment: @takeshin hi, i mean button to previous page

Comment: Then Enrico's answer is for you, but remember to display it via javascript too, to ensure that the link is displayed only when the browser supports javascript.

Answer (score 2):

What about using javascript? Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();>Back</a>
```

Comment: I guess user refers to "previous step in form" rather than "previous page" - and if so, using history.back() might not be a good option.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I cannot find any other interpretation of "previous page"